# Should I use a header for a table view controller or table inside scroll view?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uistoryboard

I'm making a chores app for fun/learning and I'm not sure the right way to implement the UI for my main page.  Here's my design below. I'd like the top score animation + the blue bar to stay put, while the chores table below it scrolls separately.

Should I use a header for a table view controller to do this, or make the chores table part of a scroll view for the entire page (or another better solution than either of these)?

I'm using Storyboard. The scores section will contain a seesaw animation, and the blue bar is a horizontal ticker with text scrolling in from the right.

[image: My UI design in Photoshop]

Comment: Many of the iOS parallax scrolling implementations use a separate view for the top content.  You don't need to embed the table in a scrollView.  Just implement the table's UIScrollViewDelegate method(s) to expand or collapse the top content when you scroll the table.